# How can I load JSON into GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, geojson, json, data-mining

I have received rainfall data in JSON format. I want to load the data into GRASS.

Sample JSON output:

> {"50.922759,-90.089954":{"current_conditions":{"air_temp":{"unit":"F","value":37.0},"cloud_cover":{"unit":"%","value":100.0},"descriptors":{"cloud_cover_descriptor":{"code":20500,
>   "text":"Cloudy"},"precipitation_descriptor":{"code":10500,
>   "visibility_obstruction_descriptor":{"code":10500,"text":"None"},"weather_descriptor":{"code":20500,"wind_direction_descriptor":{"code":52200,"text":"Variable"}},"dew_point":{"unit":"F","value":34.0},"ice_acc_last_hour":{"unit":"n/a","value":"n/a"},"liquid_acc_last_hour":{"unit":"n/a","value":"n/a"},"msl_pressure":{"unit":"mb","value":1024.0},"precip_acc_last_hour":{"unit":"n/a","value":"n/a"},"relative_humidity":{"unit":"%","value":88.0},"snow_acc_last_hour":{"unit":"n/a","value":"n/a"},"station_pressure":{"unit":"mb","value":977.0},"u_wind_speed":{"unit":"mph","value":1.9},"v_wind_speed":{"unit":"mph","value":3.0},"valid_time_end":1412048400.0,"valid_time_start":1412044800.0,"visibility":{"unit":"mi","value":10.0},"wind_direction":{"unit":"degrees","value":213.0},"wind_speed":{"unit":"mph","value":3.0}}}}

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a custom JSON format (and not GeoJSON), so I don't see any other option than reformat these data, which requires some coding:

- You can reformat it to conform GeoJSON (or any other format which is readable by OGR) and use [v.in.ogr](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.in.ogr.html).
- Or you can reformat it to GRASS ASCII format and import the point data with v.in.ascii, see [example 3](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.in.ascii.html#example-3---point-format-mode).